# Splitting JText Area into two

Tags: java, jtextarea

I'm currently programming a messanger program in Java. I have box where I type in my message and another box where it appears after I have sent it and I receive a response. The second box is JText Area and I was wonder how to I make my message appear on the right hand side of the box and the response on the left side (like iMessage). I can't seem to find how to position the strings in the jTextArea accordingly.

Comment: Can you post some code as to what you have done and probably a link to a screenshot as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `JTextArea`, try to use `JTextPane` as below.

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
frame.getContentPane().add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
textPane.setContentType("text/html");
textPane.setEditable(false);
```

After creating `JTextPane` add styles as below.

```
StyledDocument doc=textPane.getStyledDocument();
SimpleAttributeSet right =new SimpleAttributeSet();
SimpleAttributeSet left =new SimpleAttributeSet();

StyleConstants.setAlignment(right, StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT);
StyleConstants.setAlignment(left, StyleConstants.ALIGN_LEFT);
```

Now add texts to the `JTextPane`

```
   try {

        doc.insertString(0, "First Line aligned left\n", left);
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Second line Aligned right\n", right);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You will get the result as below.

[image]

Hope you got the answer you want.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you! Is there a way to make sure that longer string input does not pass the half way line of the JTextPane area?

Comment: Try these lines,

StyleConstants.setRightIndent(left, (float) textPane.getWidth()/2);
StyleConstants.setLeftIndent(right, (float) textPane.getWidth()/2);

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. The text continues past the half point line. Any Ideas?

Comment: In Design View try changing the layout of the JTextPane to 'Absolute Layout'.